# correct time to update array in state react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, lifecycle, reducers

I just started using react-redux in react applications and only project i made with react-redux was a simple json fetcher and updater, (and that was also based on crash course LOL) and now i am creating second simple application even thought it does not need redux and would perfectly work with react. so this is word / number equator. user fills in first and second input and application determines if they are equal or not and then add the equation to the history of equations (previous equations). so my problem is that i do not know when should i update `previous equations` array, in the reducer or in the lifecycle method (`componentDidUpdate`), in the crash course he updated in lifecycle method but i read that it is possible in reducer too. so which is better practice

This:

```
 export default function equateReducer(state = initialState, action) => {
     switch(action.type){
        case ADD_TO_EQUATIONS:
            return {
                ...state,
                equations: [...state, action.payload.equation]
            } 
     } 
 }
```

or this

```
componentDidUpdate(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.equation){
       this.props.equations.unshift(nextProps.equation)
    }
}
```

P.S: I really do not know how updating in lifecycle method works (I mean how does it gets nextProps.equation)

Answer (score 0):

(one of) the idea(s) behind Redux is only mutate state through defined actions

so instead of directly .unshift over equations array (I guess you connected it from mapDispatchToProps), you should be dispatching an action to achieve that same result (so your answer is: the first option looks better)

if you think redux is overkill for the task take a look at the useReducer hook